# Trying to print answer to equation and getting zero in C.

Tags: c, variables, printf, equation

```
printf("Percent decrease: ");
printf("%.2f", (float)((orgChar-codeChar)/orgChar));
```

I'm using this statement to print some results to my command console, however, I end up with zero. Putting the equation into another variable doesn't work either.

orgChar = 91 and codeChar = 13, how do I print out this equation?

Comment: are there any loop? Is orgChar value changing in each iteration?

Comment: Note that the `f` type specifier takes a `double` argument, not a `float`.

Comment: @Olaf the `float` is converted to `double` as per default argument promotions.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Sure, but why cast to `float` first? (Yes, I know it is wrongly placed)

Comment: Add the declarations of `orgChar` and `codeChar`.

Comment: How do I turn this into an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Olaf  Because otherwise the result probably has type `int`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I know. Yet the information is clearly missing.

Answer (score 8):

Integer division will lead to result 0 here and you are type casting the result later to float so eventually you will end up with 0

Make any one of the variables float before division

```
(orgChar-codeChar)/(float)orgChar
```

Comment: Btw, this still is no percentage ;) . Combine with multiplication by 100.0

Comment: I was waiting for a complete MCVE before speculating... That'll learn me!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the subtraction and division are done using integer math *before* the cast to `(float)`.  By that point, the integer division has a truncated result of 0.  Instead:

```
// (float)((orgChar-codeChar)/orgChar)
((float) orgChar - codeChar)/orgChar
// or 
(orgChar - codeChar)/ (float) orgChar
```

As the `float` argument gets converted to `double` as part of the "usual argument promotion" of arguments to a variadic function like `printf()`, might as well do

```
printf("%.2f", (orgChar-codeChar)/ (double) orgChar);
```

---

Casting, in general, should be avoided.  Some casts unintentionally *narrow* the operation. If `unsigned` is 32-bit and `a1` is `uint64_t`, then `a1` was narrowed before the shift and unexpected results may occur.  If `a1` was a `char`, it is nicely converted without trouble to an `unsigned`.

The second method of `*1u` will not narrow.  It will insure `a2*1u` is at least the width of an `unsigned`.

```
unsigned sh1 = (unsigned) a1 >> b1;  // avoid
unsigned sh2 = a2*1u >> b2;  // better
```

---

So recommend, rather than `(float)` or `(double)`, use the idiom of multiplying by 1.

```
printf("%.2f", (orgChar - codeChar) * 1.0 / orgChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to typecast the whole expression. you can simply type cast either the numerator or the denominator to get the float result with precision of 2 decimal places.
for eg:

here in this code defining a variable c as float doesnt guarantee the result to be float.for getting the precise result you need to typecast either the numerator or denominator.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't need to cast to float at all. Simply make sure both variables are of type `float` or `double` before attempting to print them as floats. This means either declaring the variables as floats, or using the correct function, such as `atof ()` when converting the data to floats (normally this is done when you get the data from the command-line or a file.)

This should work...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
    float orgChar = 91;
    float codeChar = 13;

    printf ("%.2f\n", (orgChar - codeChar) / orgChar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense when it was clearly stated that OP uses char and you have existing mechanisms of casting to float/double. "You shouldn't need to cast to float at all" - this is not true.

Comment: @zoska Nowhere do they say they are using `char` type variables. The name `orgChar` says nothing of its type, most often however, a character code is an int value. OP even assigns them using the syntax for integers, no quotes. So, yes, casting is unnecessary.

Comment: A variable called `orgChar` doesn't suggest that it might be a `char`?

Comment: @dbush No. From OP: `orgChar = 91 and codeChar = 13` do those look like values you would assign to a `char`? If you say "yes", you're doing it wrong. Both getc() and fgetc() as well as getchar() and many other functions related to character codes return integers, technically a `char` promoted to an `int`, and this is done for good reason: you need character codes to be `int` to check for `EOF`.